# Place a specific part of the text in a certain horizontal coordinate

Tags: spacing, moderncv, line-spacing

I am new to Latex and I am using a function in moderncv, `\cvitemwithcomment`, that requires three inputs and print  three texts. In my case, what I insert is:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}                             
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Languages} 
\cvitemwithcomment{Language1}{Mother tongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language2}{Some text}{This text is located on the right} 
\cvitemwithcomment{Language3}{Some longer text}{This text is located on the right and it is longer}
\end{document}
```

And what I get is:

```
 ---------- Languages
 Language1|  Mother tongue                                  
 Language2|  Some text                                    This text is located on the right
 Language3|  Some longer text                   This text is located on the right and it is longer
```

What I would like to do instead is:

```
 ---------- Languages
 Language1|  Mother tongue
 Language2|  Some text            This text is located begins at here
 Language3|  Some longer text     This text begins in the same position even if it is longer
```

i.e. make all the "third text" to start from a specific horizontal coordinate that I specify. I already tried `\flushright`. In this case my code becomes:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}                             
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Languages} 
\cvitemwithcomment{Language1}{Mother tongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language2}{Some text}{\begin{flushleft}This text begins on the left\end{flushleft}} 
\cvitemwithcomment{Language2}{Some longer text}{\begin{flushleft}This text begins on the left and it is longer\end{flushleft}}
\end{document}
```

but it does not work because if I have a different length in the second text what I get is:

```
 ---------- Languages
 Language1|  Mother tongue
 Language2|  Some text     This text begins on the left
 Language3|  Some longer text     This text begins on the left and it is longer
```

So what could I use?

Comment: I apologize, I inserted the part of my code concerning my question. I hope now it is better.

Comment: Please see question http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that to learn what a MWE is ...

Comment: For a proper MWE, (at least for LaTeX) start with `\begin{document}` and end with `\end{document}` and put the code that you have tried in between the two of those.  Its both the right thing to do, and it will garner much more attention, support, and answers. To be perfectly clear, the "part of your code concerning your question" is not quite enough.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, please may you tell me if the mwe is fine now?

Comment: @AFeldman A proper MWE for LaTeX starts `\documentclass{...}` and not `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I find the current question confusing because it seems the same inputs e.g. `{text}{text2}` are expected to produce different outputs e.g. `text text 2 (longer)` and `text (longer) text 2`, so it is difficult to see the problem or what is wanted. Your MWE should reproduce the *problem* concretely.

Comment: I can tell you that your supposed MWE is not fine, because: (1) it doesn’t compile, so it is not Working; (2) it includes calls to irrelevant packages (`geometry`, `footmisc`), so it is not Minimal; and (3) it is not even a proper Example, because, even after making the necessary corrections to the code to make it compilable, one doesn’t obtain the printout you claim to get.

Comment: @cfr certainly right.

Comment: I modified it again. Now it can be compiled and I tried to be more clear concerning the "text". Please let me know if they it clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your given MWE is nearly good, only a command `\name{Joe}{Doe}` is missing to get no error message after compiling.  I added this in the following MWE.

In your case it is the best to create an own command, for example `\mycvitemwithcomment` or `\mybcvitemwithcomment`.

In the first version I simply fixed the length for the second column in the added code to `3cm` (see `<=========`). See the following part of code (in the last line I changed `\raggedleft` to `\raggedright`):

```
\newcommand*{\mycvitemwithcomment}[4][.25em]{%
  \savebox{\cvitemwithcommentbox}{{#3}}%
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}{3cm}% <=====================
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}{\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}\usebox{\cvitemwithcommentbox}\end{minipage}%
    \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}\raggedright\small\itshape#4\end{minipage}}}
```

I showed the usage of this in section "Language 2".

If you need this new command for different length for the second column you can change the code above to the following by adding a new parameter (number 5).  But then you have to add the needed length to each call of the command `\mybcvitemwithcomment`:

```
\newcommand*{\mybcvitemwithcomment}[5][.25em]{% <==========================
  \savebox{\cvitemwithcommentbox}{{#3}}%
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}{#5}% <=========================
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}{\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}\usebox{\cvitemwithcommentbox}\end{minipage}%
    \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}\raggedright\small\itshape#4\end{minipage}}}
\makeatother
```

Then you have to use command `\mybcvitemwithcomment{Language1}{Mother tongue}{}{5cm}` for example.

I showed the usage of this in section "Language 3".

Now the complete MWE (`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are needed, because the inserted code uses `@`):

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual} % head 2, body, foot 1
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\makeatletter
\@initializebox{\cvitemwithcommentbox}
\@initializelength{\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}
\@initializelength{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}
\newcommand*{\mycvitemwithcomment}[4][.25em]{%
  \savebox{\cvitemwithcommentbox}{{#3}}%
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}{3cm}% <=====================
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}{\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}\usebox{\cvitemwithcommentbox}\end{minipage}%
    \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}\raggedright\small\itshape#4\end{minipage}}}

\newcommand*{\mybcvitemwithcomment}[5][.25em]{% <==========================
  \savebox{\cvitemwithcommentbox}{{#3}}%
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}{#5}% <=========================
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}{\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentskilllength}\usebox{\cvitemwithcommentbox}\end{minipage}%
    \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}\raggedright\small\itshape#4\end{minipage}}}
\makeatother


\name{Joe}{Doe} % <=====================================================

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Languages} 
\cvitemwithcomment{Language1}{Mother tongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language2}{Some text}{This text is located on the right} 
\cvitemwithcomment{Language3}{Some longer text}{This text is located on the right and it is longer}

\section{Languages 2} 
\mycvitemwithcomment{Language1}{Mother tongue}{}
\mycvitemwithcomment{Language2}{Some text}{This text is located on the right} 
\mycvitemwithcomment{Language3}{Some longer text}{This text is located on the right and it is longer}

\section{Languages 3} 
\mybcvitemwithcomment{Language1}{Mother tongue}{}{5cm}
\mybcvitemwithcomment{Language2}{Some text}{This text is located on the right}{5cm} 
\mybcvitemwithcomment{Language3}{Some longer text}{This text is located on the right and it is longer}{5cm}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result of mwe given above]

Just choose the variant that fits best your needs ...